# ASP.Net Modal Not Displaying

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an `ASP.Net` form which on when a 'Submit' button is clicked it sends an email.  This can take some time so i wanted to add a processing modal to the user knows that something is happening.

Now i have the modal displaying BUT it only displays once the email has either been sent of failed.  I need this modal to be displayed as soon as the button is clicked and then close once the email action has either sent it or failed the send it.

If it fails my page do currently display an error message.

**My HTML is**

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="pg3button" runat="server" OnClick="pg3button_Click" CssClass="btn btn-primary"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Send & complete</asp:LinkButton>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upModal" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblModalTitle" runat="server" Text="">Processing</asp:Label>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblModalBody" runat="server" Text="">
                                <p class="text-center">IMAGE GOES HERE</p>
                            </asp:Label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**My code behind for my `onclick` for the submit button is**

```
protected void pg3button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "myModal", "$('#myModal').modal();", true);
        upModal.Update();

        //Create the msg object to be sent
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

        //Add your email address to the recipients
        msg.To.Add("test@test.co.uk");

        //Configure the address we are sending the mail from
        MailAddress address = new MailAddress("test@test.co.uk");
        msg.From = address;

        //Append their name in the beginning of the subject
        msg.Subject = "Enquiry";

        msg.Body = Label1.Text + " " + Session["pg1input"].ToString()
                    + Environment.NewLine.ToString() +
                    Label2.Text + " " + Session["pg1dd"].ToString()
                    + Environment.NewLine.ToString() +
                    Label3.Text + " " + Session["pg2"].ToString();

        //Configure an SmtpClient to send the mail.
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com", 587);
        client.EnableSsl = true; //only enable this if your provider requires it

        //Setup credentials to login to our sender email address ("UserName", "Password")
        NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("test@test.co.uk", "Password10");
        client.Credentials = credentials;

        //MODAL CODE TO GO HERE

        //Send the msg
        client.Send(msg);

        Response.Redirect("/Session/pg4.aspx");
    }
    catch
    {
        //If the message failed at some point, let the user know
        lblResult.Text = "<div class=\"form-group\">" + "<div class=\"col-xs-12\">" + "There was a problem sending your request. Please try again." + "</div>" + "</div>" + "<div class=\"form-group\">" + "<div class=\"col-xs-12\">" + "If the error persists, please contact us." + "</div>" + "</div>";
    }
}
```

I have also tried moving the follwing code outside my `try`

```
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "myModal", "$('#myModal').modal();", true);
    upModal.Update();
```

I was think if there was a way i could call my button click then a function which has my email code in it but im new to `ASP.Net` and `webforms`

All i need is for the modal to be displayed the minute the button is clicked and removed once the page either redirects (if successful) or when my error is displayed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use JavaScript instead of server side code for modal popup

when you click on button add OnClinetClick event and use a javascript function like

```
<asp:button id="pg3button" runat="server" OnClick="pg3button_Click" OnClientclick="ShowPopup();"></asp:button>

<script>
    function ShowPopup()
    {
       $('#myModal').modal();
    }
<script>
```

also remove update panel it is not useful in this context.

Comment: return true/false is needed in script

Comment: no, it is not required, if you want to stop your button to post on certain condition then your can return true/false with your function.

Comment: @Virendrayadav Works great thanks.  Also i removed the `<asp:UpdatePanel>` and also the `<ContentTemplate>` as it still works without it

Comment: i will suggest you to read book "ASP.NET 3.5 unleashed" by Stephen Walther, it will help you to improve your basic concepts

Answer (score 1):

You are registering your script which shows modal,using the reigisterStartupScript function. Since it is a script it will get registered on the page only after the execution of your c# code. Try moving it to the aspx page itself on the onClientClick event of the button.

```
 $( "#buttonId" ).click(function() {
  $('#myModal').modal();
});
```